# Prevent automatic login when register in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am making an ecommerce website using wordpress and woocommerce. When a customer create an account from checkout page he get logged in automatically. I don't want this option. I want the user will login by himself not automatically. After searching on google i found an option to use wp approve user plugin and an action hook. http://tolinked.com/questions/4804442/prevent-automatic-login-when-register-in-woocommerce-and-redirect-to-login-page

But i don't want to use this plugin as i don't want to keep any option to approve user. There's no need to approve user. I just want don't login the user automatically after creating the account.

Thank you all.